# Return relationship count within relationship source node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a node that has relevant data that I need. That node has a relationship with multiple nodes. I would like to return the node, and the count of relationships as part of the source data. Ex:

```
(:Person)-[:Traveled]->(:Country)

(John)-[:Traveled]->(USA)
                  ->(Japan)
                  ->(Spain)
```

Plain English: John traveled to USA, Japan and Spain

I would like to return Person such that the node includes the number of countries traveled to:

```
{name:'John',..., numberOfCountriesTraveledTo: 3}
```

How can I append the result of count(:Country) as a field in John?

**UPDATE**

What if I had a relationship between two people (say friends) and I needed the path between them including the Person nodes such that the Person nodes included the count(Country)? Such that:

```
(:Person)-[:Traveled]->(:Country)

(John)-[:Traveled]->(USA)
                  ->(Japan)
                  ->(Spain)

(Kate)-[:Traveled]->(Chile)
                  ->(France)

f=(Kate)-[:Friends]-(John)
```

And returning f yields a a path with a start node something like

```
{name:'Kate',..., numberOfCountriesTraveledTo: 2}
```

and end node like

```
{name:'John',..., numberOfCountriesTraveledTo: 3}
```

My goal is to be able to return a path that includes their relationship with the count of countries in the nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just add `numberOfCountriesTraveledTo` as an additional attribute in the user projection of the result.

```
MATCH (user:User {name: 'John'})-[:TRAVELED]->(country:Country)
RETURN user{.*, numberOfCountriesTraveledTo: count(country)}
```

UPDATE - added second answer per Op's request

```
MATCH (user:User {name: 'John'})<-[:FRIENDS]-(user2:User {name: 'Kate'})
RETURN user{.*, numberOfCountriesTraveledTo: size((user)-[:TRAVELED]->())},
       user2{.*, numberOfCountriesTraveledTo: size((user2)-[:TRAVELED]->())}
```

For `n` friends in a path...

```
MATCH path=(:User {name: 'John'})<-[:FRIENDS*..10]-(:User {name: 'Kate'})
UNWIND nodes(path) as user
WITH user{.*, numberOfCountriesTraveledTo: size((user)-[:TRAVELED]->())} as user
RETURN collect(user) as users
```

Comment: Any chance you'd also know how to expand this answer to be able to get a path with nodes that have count in them? ie, the how to solve the update?

Comment: what about the rest of the information held inside the path? Like the segments, relationship information(id, etc), etc?